# How do I remove Adobe AIR?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-air

How do I remove Adobe AIR, and is that what has scrambled my legal serial number in my licensed copy of Photoshop?

Shortly after I installed a trial version of Adobe Premier Elements video editor software, my Photoshop CS1 (which has worked fine for 3.5 years on my Windows vista machine) requested that I re-activate my software. After I did, the serial number in the PS splash screen resembles: %&?]+0@.  And whenever I try to launch PS, after the splash screen, I get the error: "Invalid personalization information", and then PS just quits.

I uninstalled the Premier trial software and yet the Adobe AIR that was installed with it remains. Windows Programs and Features can not remove it- even when I booted in safe mode.

Adobe says "AIR is free so we don't support it".

Any suggestions to help me get the serial number for my licensed copy of CS1 working again?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Air is an addon to Flash which give Flash (and Flex/other) developers a bigger target market than just web browsers.

For example, [Tweetdeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com) is an application which takes advantage of Adobe Air.

If you really want to remove it, go to `Add / Remove Programs`, it is listed there and can be removed easily.

However, I highly doubt this is what caused your problems. As you have a fully legal copy of CS1, I would contact Adobe for support - that is why you paid the huge amount to begin with.

It should just be a matter of retyping the serial number and reactivating. If it does not work, then as I said, contact them or telephone them on the number that the software provides.

Comment: Easily?? AIR will not uninstall at all. I have tried countless times- even in safe mode. Explaian that. What am I dealing with here? Aodbe support says "AIR is free so we dont support it and my CS1 software is not supported for technical issues because it is so old". Yesterday, Addobe support says they fixed my serial number and yet Phostoshop is still crashing due to "Invalid personalization information". Thank you for trying anyway.